# Can a laptop access wireless network through another laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There are two laptops that are both on. One is running Ubuntu 10.10, and the other Windows XP.

There is only wireless network available, and there is no wired network here.

The Ubuntu one cannot use wireless network now for some unknown reason, but its wired network card should work fine.

The Windows one can access wireless network.

I was wondering if there is some way for the Ubuntu laptop to use the wireless network? For example, by using the Windows laptop?

---

Update:

I tried to follow the steps given in the link provided in the reply, but I don't know why it still does not work. My Windows laptop connects to a wireless, so in its wireless network connection property, under advanced tab, I selected "allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection". Then there is an error: "Internet Connection Sharing cannot be enabled. A LAN connection is already configured with the IP address that is required for automatic IP addressing."

By the way, I don't know the password of the router of the current wireless network, but I have another router whose password I know, if that may help.

Answer (score 2):

Enable ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on the Windows laptop.

See this Knowledge Base article:

> [How to configure Internet Connection Sharing in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126)

Once you've enabled ICS on the Windows XP machine, connect the two computers via an ethernet cable, and you should be able to have internet.  I'm not sure if you will have to configure anything on the Ubuntu machine, but I don't think so.  Give that a try...

Comment: Thanks! I tried to follow the link, but I don't know why it still does not work. My Windows laptop connects to a wireless, so in its wireless network connection property, under advanced tab, I selected "allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection". Then there is an error: "Internet Connection Sharing cannot be enabled. A LAN connection is already configured with the IP address that is required for automatic IP addressing."